# Jquery plugin working after i hit the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm writing a webpage where the result from database has to be displayed based on the selected dates. Here I'm using `jquery datepicker` to select dates and below is my code.

**Index.html**

```
</head>
<body>
    <marquee>
        <h1>This is an example of ajax</h1>
    </marquee>

    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
    </p>

    <form name="vinform">
        Enter id:<input type="button" id="somebutton" value="Click Me">
    </form>
    <span id="somediv"> </span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tableGenerator.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**tableGenerator.js**

```
$('#somebutton').click(
        function() {
            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
            $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
            $.getJSON('Controller', {
                //the parameters go here
            }, function(searchList) {
                var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
                $.each(searchList, function(index, userBean) {
                    $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.caseNumber)).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.caseOwner)).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.status)).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.issue)).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.reason)).append(
                            $('<td>').text(userBean.age));
                });
            });
        });
```

Here I need to select the dates first and then when i hit submit, it should display the table. But in my case, when i click on the date picker textbox, that doesn't work, but instead if i click the button, and then if i click on the datepicker textbox, it works fine.

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call this:

```
 $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
 $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
```

Out of the Click function, or will only apply the datepicker when user click on the button.

So you need to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker(); 
});
```

So, with this you will apply the datepicker on the page load, without click on the button

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
$("#endDatePicker").datepicker();

$('#somebutton').click( function() {


    $.getJSON('Controller', {
        //the parameters go here
    }, function(searchList) {
        var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
        $.each(searchList, function(index, userBean) {
            $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.caseNumber)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.caseOwner)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.status)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.issue)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.reason)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.age));
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
});

$('#somebutton').click(
    function() {
        $.getJSON('Controller', {
            //the parameters go here
        }, function(searchList) {
        var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
        $.each(searchList, function(index, userBean) {
            $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.caseNumber)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.caseOwner)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.status)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.issue)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.reason)).append(
                    $('<td>').text(userBean.age));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Datepicker option outside and inside your Some Button Click.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    

    // Date Picker         
    $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();

    $('#somebutton').click( function() {


        $.getJSON('Controller', {
            //the parameters go here
        }, function(searchList) {
            var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
            $.each(searchList, function(index, userBean) {
                $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.caseNumber)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.caseOwner)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.status)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.issue)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.reason)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.age));
            });
        });

        // Date Picker         
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
            $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
            $.getJSON('Controller', {
                //the parameters go here
            }, function(searchList) {
            var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
            $.each(searchList, function(index, userBean) {
                $('<tr>').appendTo($table).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.caseNumber)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.caseOwner)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.status)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.issue)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.reason)).append(
                        $('<td>').text(userBean.age));
            });
        });

    });
```

working [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wc1bgmun/)